# How do I create hard margins through an entire HTML/CSS layout that don't impact the background or current container?

Tags: html, css

[image: My attempt:]
[image: Example page:]

Scenario: I am currently working through a CSS/HTML project and have to recreate an example web-page using flexbox.

Problem: I seem to be unable to mimic the margin/indenting that the example page is using on either side of the page.

[image]
When I attempt to copy this in various ways, I end up indenting the entire header block, and I'm left with whatever colour the body is behind.

Comment: try padding, not margin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Margin is an attribute that defines the outside range of the box you are working in. It will increase the whitespace outside of the box.

What you want is increase the whitespace inside of the box. This spacing is called padding.

```
body {
  padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should probably check out the "padding" propriety in CSS on the body tag of your page.